# Is there close button built in asp.net mvc views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

Is there (and how to include if exist), "close" button in asp.net mvc view?

Something similar to windows form but in ASP.NET MVC (VIEW) ?

[image]

Thanks
Cheers

Comment: why did you need a close button?  Is it a pop up?

Comment: @abdul I need to show small amount of data, It can be view or modal I don't know what practice is better, I need to show only 2 dates like START DATE END DATE and close if users want to close it all..

Comment: How are you displaying the data? Are you using a modal?

Comment: @Kramb I did not decide yet how I will display the data, modal or view I don't know which is better because I need to choose dates and send them to another form, but for now I'm wondering about this buttons

Comment: The simplest answer is yes, MVC has buttons that work similar to winforms. You have to build them and provide them with functionality though.

Comment: Would something like this suffice?
https://jsfiddle.net/Kramb/ns3hyp5o/

Comment: The functionality is not part of MVC itself, it is achieved by combining HTML div & jQuery modal popup script. Perhaps @Kramb already shown basic functionality you want to implement with.